# Thread Safety with Classes an Accessors

Tags: multithreading, winapi, thread-safety

Okay so I have three classes, `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo`, and `ClassThree`.

`ClassOne` is ran in the `Main` Thread, `ClassTwo` is ran in Thread `ThreadTwo`, and `ClassThree` is ran in `ThreadThree`.
In `ClassTwo` and in `ClassThree` I make calls to `ClassOne` and vice-versa.

```
    ClassTwo::SomeMethod(){
    int l_SomeVar = m_ClassOnePointer->SomeAccessorMethod() // return m_SomeVariable
    int l_SomeVar = m_ClassOnePointer->SomeConstAccessor()  // SomeConstAccessor() const;
    int l_SomeVar = m_ClassOnePointer->m_SomeVariable;      // Just a standard public int (not const, static, or volatile).

    m_ClassOnePointer->m_SetSomeVariable(30);
    m_ClassOnePointer->m_SomeVariable = 30;
```

Currently I use accessors and const accessors, but I don't know if its safe for threading, If it isn't how would I go about safely doing this without locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe.  As for getters for arbitrary types without locks - I've got nuthin..   The const doesn't help - just because the getter declares it's not going to change member vars doesn't mean some other threads can't change them. Other threads may call setters, or perhaps ClassOne has an internal thread that's changing them.

Comment: I didn't use the const for threading safety, it was just required for some of the accessors.

Comment: And I can't make an internal thread, I have a limit of only 6 threads.